# NSFetchedResusltsController announces a move but it should be an update

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableview which get its data from an NSFetchedResultsController. It organizes the data into sections according to a NSDate attribute. Inside each section, the data is also organized by an NSDate attribute.

Occasionally, I have to call a webservice in order to retrieve some data to update my list. This data can be an insert or an update of an existing data.

Here is my problem : When Core Data end the data recording, my NSFetchedResultsController asks its delegate to move some rows ... but these rows should have been updated, not moved.

These rows correspond to some entities I just updated. But the updates never occur on the attributes that I use to order my data. These rows shouldn't move ! In fact, this bug doesn't occur for every entity I update, but just some of them. They are always the same but they don't have anything special, they are like the others ...

I read an article in Apple's documentation about moved objects who where sometimes reported as updated but that's not my problem unfortunately.

There is a lot of code going on there from the creation of the NSFetchedResultsController (with its request, predicate and sortDescriptors), the handling of the changes notified by the NSFetchedResultsController, the registering of the data etc etc. Tell what piece you want, I'll post it.

Thank you in advance guys !

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, you are probably using the same context for the update and for the web service.
If yes, you should have at least two context, one for the controller, and one for the update.

Then you can merge the two, temporarily resigning the fetched controller from being delegate. And reassigning when update has finished, and then re issue the fetch. You avoid many cells moving that could freeze your UI for a while.

Also, NSFetchedResultsController react not only on saving of context, but also when a new entity is created but not saved.

Which is by calling:

```
NSManagedObject *mo = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:myEntityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:ctx];
```

a new cell take its place in tableview, all the others are moved.

If 'move' is called, it sounds like your UIViewController is still a delegate for your fetched controller.

The usual way, at least for me or from what I have seen around, is to have the controller re issue the fetch, and then call reloadData on your table view.

Otherwise, keep in mind that even if you change a relationship, your controller is going to react on those changes.

To debug, you could register your UIViewController as observer for  NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidSaveNotification , put a breakpoint and see what property is triggering the wrong move.

Comment: In fact, I already have two contexts. I'm doing all my Core Data updates in background, using GCD and when everything is done, I merge the two contexts. So it's only when the merge is over that my NSFRC call its delegate.

Comment: are you sure that during merge you have removed NSFRC as delegate ? Also, the context notify that a NSManagedObject is changed, is not observing a particular value, and the NSFRC react to those changes anyway. Even if you change a relationship, the context notify that parent has changed.

Comment: Nope I don't remove my viewController as a delegate of my NSFRC. The reason I don't want to do this is because I'd like to have the nice transitioning animations when a cell is added. For a debugging purpose, I'm requesting all the data to my web services. So every entity is updated with the same values it had before the update. In this situation, my NSFRC doesn't call its delegate for every updated entity (I guess it detects that it has no real changes) but just for some rows (even if these entities have no real changes). I hope I'm clear ...